# Remove common string from a string using jquery or plain Javascript

Tags: javascript

How can remove the 'tp.' from below string from each place where it is coming

```
str = " tp.FirstName, tp.FamilyName, tp.DOB, tp.TypeOfLocation
WHERE

tp.DateStamp BETWEEN '2012-02-12 15:13:00' AND '2013-02-12 15:13:00'

AND tp.db_name_id =21
AND

tp.FirstName = 'Darlene'";
```

I need result as below:

```
FirstName, FamilyName, DOB, TypeOfLocation
WHERE

DateStamp BETWEEN '2012-02-12 15:13:00' AND '2013-02-12 15:13:00'

AND db_name_id =21
AND

FirstName = 'Darlene'";
```

Comment: use replace function in javascript

Comment: @RuneFS: that implies that JavaScript is jQuery (Since both sides of a `=` sign can be switched around). What I'm trying to say is: jQuery is a JS library. Saying "JavaScript or jQuery" makes perfect sense, since there's a difference between using native JS and jQuery.

Comment: @Cerbrus well if you wanna be mathematically about it then (for the fun of it) for x is y to be symmetric as you imply then x is not y should also be symmetric. That is `jQeury is not javascript` and `javascript is not jquery`should both be either true or false. Which is not the case. Further the mathematical binary relation equality is also transitive so if the is was indeed a mathematical operation then "jquery is javascript" and "javascript is a scripting language" would also imply that "jquery is a scripting language" which is clearly not the case either :)

Comment: You're missing the point here, @RuneFS, instead you're nitpicking about my abuse of math.
You make a comment about the title, and I state that the title makes sense because there is a difference between _using_ jQuery and JS. You say JQ is JS, but that's totally irrelevant in the context of the question.

Comment: @Rune FS : you are also right, actually jquery is library file of javascript. 
AND This issue can be solve using both way but jquery reduce the lot of JS code.


If I asked this question only for javascript then stackfollers give me answer in javascript. And I want just solution for that so both way is okay for me but jquery is first priority.

whatever, just thanks for your suggestion and clear the things

Comment: @Cerbrus not missing the point just disagreeing (and having fun as I stated) with the difference of unambiguous math and ambiguous English.  Sorry if that upset you since that was not the intention

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple:

```
str = str.replace(/\btp\./g, '');
```

This uses a regex to search for all occurrences of `tp\.` in the string, and replaces them with a empty string, effectively removing it.
(The period is escaped, since that's a special character in regexes. It literally searches for `tp.`.
The `\b` is a word boundary, making sure that `tp.` is at the start of a word.)

Or, the `split`/ `join` method:

```
str = str.split('tp.').join('');
```

This will split up the string at every occurrence of `'tp.'` (Without copying that along), then join the array together, resulting in a string where `'tp.'` was removed.

Comment: I'd use `/\btp\./` just in case.